# How to find the Range of Cell in excel - Qt?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have cell's value as row and column.

```
Cells(1,10); //1 is row and 10 is column
```

Now i want to identify the Range of of that cell location.

```
J1; //where j is column and 1 is row
```

Is there any possibility to find out in QT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the object model

```
Cells(5, 3).address(true,true,xlA1)
```

would return `"$C$5"`

Comment: Thanks Alex. And     QAxObject * range = temp_Worksheet->querySubObject("Cells(int,int)",row,col);     I got cell's value in this way. so how can i get the range now ?

Comment: Something like `range->dynamicCall("Address(bool, bool, int)",true,true,1);`